# Upload application to Ingenico iCT250

Tags: payment

How can I upload application to Ingenico iCT250? I connected it through USB and installed the driver and tried the millenium uploader but it is do not connect to the POS.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the proper tool, called "LLT".
Those tool are deliverd from INGENICO itself after you follow the proper registration and validation.
You cannot get them elsewhere.
Other than you have to sign the application with a recognized key.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload your application without signing.